# make sudoers use their own history file

Tags: sudo, bashrc

I just can't seem to get a simple answer to this one. All I am trying to do is get a sudoers to use their own history file, but if I set the history var in the `.bashrc` for `root` with `$user`, the `$user` is already `root`, so it has no effect.

In theory I have to set the history file (`.bash_history`) in sudoers I guess, but I can't seem to find a simple answer for this. It can't be that complicated, or am I wrong?

Current System is Standard CentOS 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the history file to `~root/.bash_history.$SUDO_USER`, where `$SUDO_USER` is automatically set to the user who invoked sudo.  For example, the following could go in your root bashrc:

```
HISTFILE="$HOME/.bash_history.$SUDO_USER"
```

Comment: one could also use HISTFILE="/home/$SUDO_USER/.bash_history" I guess. I was looking for the VAR $SUDO_USER :) Simple and effective, thanks @user3188445

Comment: this option does not apply for Ubuntu. It seems Ubuntu does the history a bit different.

Comment: @WillemP.Botha: It's not an ubuntu thing, but a bash thing: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-HISTFILE .  Maybe ubuntu doesn't use bash for root (what does it use?  zsh), but the question was specifically about bash.  Also, don't set the history to your home directory, as this is both a security problem (root is now writing places it shouldn't and can be tricked by symlinks) and a usability problem (you may end up with a root-owned history file you cannot write yourself).

Comment: valid point, changing the location to /root rather than $HOME :)